# Error 800CCC0F-0-0-322 Synchronizing IMAP Sent folder in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, imap

I'm getting multiple 800CCC0F-0-0-322 errors when synchronizing some of the emails in my customers sent folders on two of her IMAP mailboxes. The sync errors seem to happen on the same emails every time. I've compared some of the suspect emails in  Outlook 2013 sent folder to the webmail version and they appear in both places as expected. One of the mailboxes is TalkTalk the other is Yahoo.

I've tried removing the accounts from Outlook 2013 and setting them up again but it doesn't get rid of the errors.

Aside from these errors, sending and receiving appear to work fine.

My customer seem to think that the problem may have started when the CMOS battery on the desktop died and the machine was showing the wrong time. Why Windows didn't check the Windows time server and reset it I don't know. This could be a red herring but it's worth stating to give a fuller picture.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've earned a tumbleweed badge for this question ...yay ..  onwards and upwards

Answer (score 0):

This problem is known to happen when e.g. Outlook allows for larger mails (e.g. 30 mb) than the IMAP store (e.g. 20 mb).

Unfortunately, the only remedy I have found is to delete the mail. Alternatively you sometimes can get the mail provider to enlarge your max limit.